# Looping Json & Display in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

How do I go about looping the result i retrieved from Json? 
[image]

```
render: function() {
     console.log(this.state.list);
     contents = (
      <View style={ styles.content }>
        <Text>Loaded</Text>

      </View>
     )
     return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <View style={ styles.header }>
        <Text style={ styles.headerText }>XXX</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={ styles.content }>
            { contents }
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React can render an array of Elements, so you just need to construct an array and assign it to your `contents` variable. I made an example using `map`.

```
render: function() {
     console.log(this.state.list);
     contents = this.state.list.results.map(function (item) {
        return (
          <View key={item.user.email} style={ styles.content }>
            <Text>{item.user.email}</Text>
          </View>
        );
     });
     return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <View style={ styles.header }>
        <Text style={ styles.headerText }>XXX</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={ styles.content }>
            { contents }
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And also: when you have an array of elements in React, you should provide a unique `key` attribute to each element in the array. [See why](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children). In this case, I use `item.user.email` as the unique identifier, but you can use another attribute, just make sure it unique (`item.user.md5` is promising)

Comment: Make sure the `this.state.list` object always has `results` array in it. You could add more logic to handle your state or just add if/else condition to get your desired `contents`.

Comment: i initialised by using list: {results:[]} at getInitialState

Comment: but i'm getting warning : each child in an array or iterator should have a unique key prop, please advice :)

Comment: That was my mistake not putting the `key` attribute. Check my updated answer.